# Numpy: Packing N bits per byte

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy in GNURadio, where there are variable numbers of bits that should be packed into a given byte based on the type of modulation. Not really relevant for this question, but that's the background.

With numpy, how can I take an array of bits, and repack it into `N` bits per byte?

For example, if I have a bit array `[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]` and I want to pack 2 bits per byte, my output array should look like `[1, 3, 0, 2]`. If I want to pack 4 bits per byte, the output should look like `[7, 2]`.

The [`np.packbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) function doesn't have a parameter for bits-per-byte. Any suggestions for a high-performance solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) and [`packbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html)

```
def packbits(arr, bits_per_byte):
    arr = np.reshape(arr, (-1, bits_per_byte))
    arr = np.pad(arr, 
           pad_width=((0, 0), (8 - arr.shape[1], 0)))
    return np.packbits(arr, axis=1)
```

---

```
>>> bits = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
>>> print(packbits(bits, 2)) 
[[1]
 [3]
 [0]
 [2]]

>>> print(packbits(bits, 4))
[[7]
 [2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. It's putting each packed byte into its own array though; how would I modify this to have it output a 1-dimensional array?

Comment: @Jordan You can always `.flatten()`, `.ravel()` or `.reshape()` at the end ;)